# How do I restore Ubuntu's default interface?

Tags: unity, nvidia, 13.04, sudo, gnome2

When I downloaded and install nvidia drivers, both the top bar and bottom bar disappeared. When I removed them, some applications worked, but the bars are still missing and fancy shortcuts such as alt+tab don't work. Thus, I'm not sure how I can restore a screen I minimized. How do I restore it as it was, or should I use this time as opportunity for change?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://askubuntu.com/q/17381/54949. Maybe this answer can help: http://askubuntu.com/a/286349/54949.

Comment: The first answer was a lot more helpful than the one specifically about 13.04. Nonetheless, thank you for the links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next time, when I am doing a Google search, I must remember certain keywords: "dash" and "launcher". The answer is this: https://askubuntu.com/a/76951/110280

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the easier way is to setup a new account from scratch and to get all of the data you need from /home/your_username to /home/your_new_username afterwards.

Comment: I don't have enough pen drives and cd's to save everything I want.